# After searching a hashmap, how do I have it highlight result in jlist?

Tags: java, search, jbutton, jlist

I have created a program that allows you to enter a country/capital in 2 separate jtextfields on click from a jbutton, this adds the capital ( which is the value in the hashmap ) ( it also sets country as the key in the hashmap, but does not display it in the jlist )

After the jList is populated, I have a separate jtextfield/ jbutton that you enter the country to search for and it is supposed to highlight the capital in the Jlist

How do I get it to highlight the capital in the jlist after search ( or after the search jbutton is pressed ? )

Something like this?
searchText.setText(search);
String search = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Java API on JLists:

> Painting of cells in a JList is handled by a delegate called a cell renderer, installed on the list as the cellRenderer property. The renderer provides a java.awt.Component that is used like a "rubber stamp" to paint the cells. Each time a cell needs to be painted, the list's ListUI asks the cell renderer for the component, moves it into place, and has it paint the contents of the cell by way of its paint method. A default cell renderer, which uses a JLabel component to render, is installed by the lists's ListUI.

And here's the link to read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html